# concurently hit the wakama clients to leshan server with out load testing tools in python language

Tags: iot, leshan

100k of wakama clients concurently hitting to leshan server with out jmeter  or any testing tools in python 
A python client in git is found which has wrote using asyncio coroutines i would like to modify the client code and achieve concurent hits of the clients how will be achieved?

Comment: can we achieve concurrency using asyncio? what will the best way to achieve that concurent hits in python language.

Comment: "Lakh" for 100,000 is not broadly used outside of India, so people wouldn't know that means, I think. It's also not clear what you're asking, to me.